# Check if a file is already committed to svn

Tags: svn, shell-script

How do I check if a file/folder is already committed to svn ? I have a shell script where I want to ensure that the file/folder selected by user for check-in isn't already committed. 
For eg if I try to check-in a folder that's already committed
using

> svn add myfolder

I get the following warning:

> svn: warning: 'myfolder' is already under version control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the return code of `svn info`. It's `0` if under version control, non-zero otherwise.

My shell displays non-zero return codes after a command, so it looks like this:

```
$ svn info trunk
Path: trunk
URL: https://(...)/trunk
Repository Root: https://(...)
Repository UUID: 651713a4-5a46-7e42-a99e-f31e79777eab
Revision: 213
Node Kind: directory
(...)

$ touch foo
$ svn info foo 
foo:  (Not a versioned resource)

svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details

rc: 1
```

How you'd do it in a  `bash` script (similar in other shells), with suppressing `info` output:

```
svn info <filename> 1>/dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```

Comment: As a one-liner in bash: `[[ $(svn info $file 1>/dev/null 2>&1) == 0 ]] && echo "$file is under version control`

Comment: @derFunk Or just `(svn info $file 1>/dev/null 2>&1) && echo "$file is under version control"`. Plus the line where you define `file`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
if [ $(svn status $file | awk '{ print $1 }') == "?" ]; then
    echo "File is not under version control"
fi
```

This way you can also query different svn status codes which can be seen here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to solve a similar problem: As part of a script which generated a file, automatically add it to subversion if this had not been done previously.

I found the following worked:

```
if ! svn info ${file} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  svn add ${file}
fi
```

[Testing exit values in Bash](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/testing-exit-values-bash/) led me to this answer.